# ajax in laravel reloads a blank page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use ajax to get back data from a database on a button click. Right now when I click the button a blank page is reloaded. I am not sure why this is happening or how I can fix it.

Here is the code in my view:

```
<form action="test" method="post" id="testForm">
  <input name="input1" type="form"> </input> <br>
  <input name="input2" type="form"> </input> <br>
  <button type="submit" class="sbutton"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Javascript Code also in view between script tags, (I know not good practice, will move to separate file later).

```
$('#testForm').submit(function(e){
  var rawElement = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
  $.post('test', formData).done(function(response){
      console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Here is the code in my Controller:

```
public function getValues()
{
  $input1= $_POST["input1"];
  $input2= $_POST["input2"];
  try{
      DB::table("table")->insert(
          array("value1" => $input1, "value2" => $input2)
      );
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      echo "something went wrong";
  }
  $object = new \App\testClass($userID); // $object is a custom object
   return $userObject;
}
```

Code in my routes files:

```
Route:: post("test",
["as" => "test",
"uses" => "tableController@getValues"]);

Route::get("test", "PagesController@getValues"); // This just returns the page
```

So right now the controller function is returning a blank page with the object. I am trying to use ajax in laravel to get the controller function to just pass the object to the current page without a page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to place the form inside a body tag and change input fields to have type text. Below is the view file with the corrected code

```
<body>
<form action="test" method="post" id="testForm">
<input name="input1" type="text"> </input> <br>
<input name="input2" type="text"> </input> <br>
<button type="submit" class="sbutton"> Submit </button>
</form>


<script>

$('#testForm').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(this).serialize(); //Get the form data and put in a structure i can send
  $.post('test', formData).done(function(response){
      console.log(response);
  });
 });
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests) layer to access any POST data.

```
public function getValues(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->input();

    $input1= $input["input1"];
    $input2= $input["input2"];.

    try {
        DB::table("table")->insert(
            array("value1" => $input1, "value2" => $input2)
        );

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd("something went wrong");
    }

    $object = new \App\testClass($userID); // $object is a custom object
    return $object;
}
```

Comment: my understanding is that $_POST["input1"]; is the same thing, maybe not best practice but is functional.

Comment: This answer is probably right, maybe return a json response in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var data = $("#testForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/yourURL",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {

                   alert("Your message sent!");
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: tried this but same result, the problem might be in the routes files. I will edit my post with them in a few min